# Sorting an Excel Spreadsheet with Python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, xlrd

this is my first post and my programming knowledge is rather limited. I would appreciate if answers are given using python since that is the only language I am familiar with. I have also tried using pandas and xlrd, so continuing with those would be nice.

The problem is this: I have a list of companies that is about 30,000 entries long. The list is in the form of a Google Sheet, but this can easily be exported to Excel. Each row of the sheet represents a company, and each column represents a piece of info pertaining to that company.

My boss wants a team of us to go through this sheet and sort each company into categories based upon their industry, this would obviously take a very long time. It involves searching up each company name, finding its industry, then copying the row on the unsorted sheet and pasting it into a row on the categorized sheet.

My thought was that using if statements, we could sort through a good chunk of the work pretty fast.

For example, let's say a category of companies was called "Construction". If the company name contains the words "construction", "steel" or something of the sort, we could automatically move that company (and all its info) to this new category called "Construction". The new destination would preferably be a sheet on a new excel file. Any items that don't have any of the industry keywords in them go into the unsorted sheet.

What I struggle with is finding a way to sort through the data, keep all of the info pertaining to each company together, and moving/copying a row from one place to another. What functions might I use? How might I tackle this?

The goal is to have MOST, not all, of the 30,000 entries sorted automatically based on their names, so I may only need to sort through a few thousand unsorted items that didn't match any keywords manually.

Any help with this issue is greatly appreciated, and I'm more than happy to provide any additional details anyone may need to help this working.

Comment: This is more of a conceptual question than a specific coding question, but as a basic approach, look into pandas` [`.str.contains()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) function for searching text strings.

Comment: As far as 'moving data', you should be able to read your Google sheet directly with pandas, add new columns based on filtering, then export a CSV/Excel file to your desktop or a server I'm unsure if you can modify the Google sheet in-place using python, but a manual export/upload isn't too bad, especially as you'll likely need to code some entries by hand.

Comment: It would help to have 10 or so entries of sample data to look at... _but_ it sounds like having a list of keywords mapped to a dict could be what you need to classify each company. for example:
`keyword_dict = { 'Construction': ['construction', 'steel', 'contractor'], 'Energy': ['power', 'light', 'energy'], ...}`
Then you can use python's builtin `csv` module to parse and edit csv files, or other modules like `openpyxl` for working with excel worksheets.
would love to help out more, but without more specific info it's difficult :)

Answer (score 0):

The hard part will be writing a function `get_category()` that takes a row and returns a category. Once you have that, you can do things like `df['category'] = df.apply(get_category,axis = 1)`, which will insert a column saying what category the companies are, or `category_dict = {category[0]: category[1] for category in df.groupby(df.apply(get_category,axis= 1)}`, which will create a dictionary in which each key is a category and the corresponding value is a dataframe of the companies in that category.

For `get_category`, you might want to look into the `requests` module. You can automatically take the company name and see whether you can find websites regarding that company, and then search those websites for keywords.